# Redirect URI for Discord OAuth2 Bot

Tags: discord, discord-jda

When creating the invite link for my Discord bot, I require a Redirect URI for Scopes other than Bot and Application.Commands.

I followed some other questions on SO, but the solution (general Discord Authorise link with client ID) does not work.
Instead of working to add the bot with the given scopes, it instead gives the bot no Scopes other than “bot”.
I use JDA for the bot and I require some additional Scopes like messages.read to read every sent message.
How do I generate the Redirect URI properly?

Comment: You redirect back to a URL you control. You decide what that URL is.

Comment: Bots can read every message without that scope.